# How to add physical special keys to a computer?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Large applications such as Android Studio have lots of complicated, hard-to-remember shortcut keys, for example, "Shift + F6" for rename. I was thinking about adding physical keys for some of the features I often use, so I searched Amazon, and they only things they sell are number pads. I could not find any "generic keypads" whose keys can be mapped for anything.

So, for example, if I buy a [keypad like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07D4JDLQF), I would need to map those keys on the wireless keypad to things like Shift + F6. But I do not want the the number pad keys on my main keyboard to be affected. Is this possible?

I am not limiting to Windows. If it is not possible on Windows, but possible on Linux, do let me know.

Comment: This is the first google result, is this what you want? https://www.instructables.com/id/Making-a-powerful-programmable-keypad-for-less-tha/

Comment: [Elgato Stream Deck](https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming/stream-deck) - not a keyboard, supports submenus, you can customize key icons. Quite pricey, though.

Comment: There are gaming keyboards out there with macro functionality. You can record a macro with each keypress or bind their buttons to a keypress directly. Lots of possibilities if you go this route.

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest option is probably going to be replacing your keyboard with one that has macro buttons. Optionally there are mice that have macro buttons too, but that is probably going to be more expensive.

The macro buttons on these keyboards are extra and either can be mapped to execute one or more keypresses, or can be mapped to execute a key combination directly. In either case you can do this.

These keyboards are often categorized as gaming keyboards, but there are also normal looking gaming keyboards with macro buttons.

[Get a list of currently available prouducts amazon](https://www.amazon.com/slp/keyboard-with-macro-keys/gnyyx93vhu2484f), or search for one on your local retail store. I will not do a hardware recommendation though. Any keyboard with macro functionality will work.

EDIT: A cheaper option is to use pen and paper, write down the functions and their respective keyboard shortcuts, and look at that when you forgot the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with LPChip's answer, I would elaborate on it. You might like your keyboard and not want to replace it. There are a variety of gaming keyboards, AKA gameboards that you can use in conjunction with your keyboard. I have a Logitech G13.  What's nice about the Logitech, is the macro keys are programmable per application. This means you can set a key to emulate a series of keypresses in Android Studio and the same key can perform different keypresses in Visual Studio.  I can't speak towards other brands/models, but i would assume/hope the have similar functionality.

Comment: "doeak" now that's an interesting word I never heard of... xD

Comment: @LPChip typically on a phone in a car. Lol.